# Browsers behave different when doing XHR request with large json data

Tags: jquery, performance

The issue with this is connection being reset from the browser after trying to download large JSON data for the GET action

The time is divided as follows

First Byte transfer from server to browser starts around 30 to 35 seconds
Remaining content(around 600kb) transfer takes different times in different browsers as below

1. Firefox takes 50 seconds for remaining bytes transfer and is success all times
2. Internet explorer takes huge time 3 min but fails sometimes.
3. Chrome snaps around 30 seconds after the transfer starts with connection reset error

We use jQuery version 1.11 and Struts 2.3

Did anyone experience such issues. Can someone highlight how do i understand this better and how i can resolve this?

Comment: Just a point to note, Its $.ajax that we call and not direct XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not transfer big data over network. The network may be busy and have errors on the line that prevents data transmitting. A huge data load impacts the client and the browser that allocate the memory for storage the data down stream.

The browser is using there own implementation of network loading. You can debug  the performance in the network tab of developer tools.

So you first chance to improve the reset connection error is to divide the data by chunks and transmit a single chunk of data 1-5k in the single request.

I understand that it's impossible to you even if you use

> jquery version 1.11 and struts 2.3

Updating versions of both may be better choice for you.

Comment: Thanks for insight, appreciate your response